# Kotlin multiplatform support for Optional

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working with a Java API now converted into *multiplatform* Kotlin. It used to use `java.lang.Optional` as the return type of many calls. I understand this is [not the idiomatic Kotlin-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529644/should-kotlins-dao-return-optional-or-null) (see [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/java-api-design-for-kotlin-consumption-optional-or-null/2455/16)) but this is an existing API, Optional stays (also it isn't a *bad* choice for the Java-facing client). My question is *how*?

**Note:** The code only needs to `return Optional.of(x)` or `return Optional.empty()` to the external API. Any internal uses will be purged.

- How do we use [`expect`/`actual`/`typealias`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/platform-specific-declarations.html) to use the *real* `Optional` class when available?
- Is there a way to avoid re-implementing a *fake* Optional class on non-Java targets (i.e. work idiomatically with nullable`?` suffix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, Kotlin doesn't allow providing an `actual typealias` for an expected class with a `companion object` by using a Java class with matching `static` declarations. Follow this issue for updates: [KT-29882](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29882).

For now, you can workaround that by declaring the factory functions separately, outside the expected `Optional` class, as follows:

```
expect class Optional<T : Any> {
    fun get(): T
    fun isPresent(): Boolean
    /* ... */
}

expect object Optionals {
    fun <T : Any> of(t: T): Optional<T>
    fun empty(): Optional<Nothing>
}
```

<sup>That should not necessarily be an `object`, you could just use top-level functions.</sup>

Then, on the JVM, you would have to provide an `actual typealias` for the `Optional` class and, additionally, provide the trivial actual implementation for the `Optionals` object:

```
actual typealias Optional<T> = java.util.Optional<T>

actual object Optionals {
    actual fun <T : Any> of(t: T): Optional<T> = java.util.Optional.of(t)
    actual fun empty(): Optional<Nothing> = java.util.Optional.empty()
}
```

As for not providing an implementation for the non-JVM platforms, I doubt it's possible, as that would require some non-trivial compile-time transformations of the `Optional` usages to just the nullable type. So you would want something like this:

```
actual typealias Optional<T> = T?
```

which is now an error:

> Type alias expands to `T?`, which is not a class, an interface, or an object

So you actually need a non-JVM implementation. To avoid duplicating it for every non-JVM target, you can declare a custom source set and link it with the platform-specific source sets, so they get the implementation from there:

<sub>`build.gradle.kts`</sub>

```
kotlin {
    /* targets declarations omitted */

    sourceSets {
        /* ... */

        val nonJvmOptional by creating {
            dependsOn(getByName("commonMain"))
        }
        configure(listOf(js(), linuxX64())) { // these are my two non-JVM targets
            compilations["main"].defaultSourceSet.dependsOn(nonJvmOptional)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, inside this custom source set (e.g. in `src/nonJvmOptional/kotlin/OptionalImpl.kt`) you can provide an actual implementation for the non-JVM targets.

Here's a minimal project example on Github where I experimented with the above: [`h0tk3y/mpp-optional-demo`](https://github.com/h0tk3y/mpp-optional-demo)

Comment: `actual typealias Optional<T> = T?` would be awesome if it worked.

Comment: @drekbour, as far as I can tell, this is almost the only viable use case for such a type alias, and it would require non-trivial rules, and that's why it was left prohibited.